# Flask-Restx: How to specify Swagger Request Body Expectation if Resource resides in a different module than the app/api?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, microservices, flask-restx

All Swagger docs (https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger.html) assume that the instantiation of the api is in the same place as the Resource.
But if I have an `app.py` of the form

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Api

from resources.item import Item
from resources.item import ItemList

app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Item, "/item/<string:name>")
api.add_resource(ItemList, "/items")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=4999)
```

How can I specify the `api.expect()` in `resources/item.py` without generating a circular dependency, i.e. something along the line of:

```
from flask_restx import Resource, fields
from app import api # GENERATES CIRCULAR IMPORT
items = [] # in-memory database

class Item(Resource):      
    @api.expect(body=api.model(
            'Post Request Body', 
            {
                'price': fields.Float,
                'id': fields.Integer
            }
    ) 
) 
    def post(self, name):
        if next(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == name,  items), None):
            return {'message': f"An item with name {name} already exists."}, 400 # bad request

        data = FlaskItemModel.parser.parse_args() 
        item = {'name': name, 'price': data['price']}
        items.append(item)
        return item, 201 # CREATED (202 - ACCEPTED, delayed creation)
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to have the resources separate from the api and generate the Swagger docs for the Request Body properly without generating a circular loop like above?

Comment: What about creating an api.py with `from flask_restx import Api
api = Api()`
then in app.py you can import it and do `api.init_app(app)`

If you want to have resources in other modules you just import from api.py